# Visits per day for sites in private beta are bugged

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, private-beta

The visits of [Fitness & Nutrition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/fitness-nutrition), [Skeptics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics), and of [Drupal Answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers) are all set to zero on Area51.

Comment: Seems about right then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visits per day is not supported until the site is in public beta. The site is private, so visits will be quite low anyway.

Comment: If so, that is a new change. The day after Skeptics' private beta started, I remember very well seeing it had 100 visits per day. In either case, you should think of something clearer to display than zero.

Comment: @bor correct, it is now driven by Google Analytics. As you can imagine, a site that Google cannot *see* they cannot *measure* (private betas are .. private)

Comment: Skeptics.SE now has [42 visits per day](http://i.imgur.com/dxL8h.png), even though it's still in private beta.

Comment: @bor just don't expect those stats to be reliable until public beta